# How does one rewrap text in a column in Vim?

Tags: vim

I have column-oriented text of the form:

```
TR #  DATE        DESCRIPTION                  PROGRAMMER
----- ----------- ---------------------------  -----------
12345 01-APR-2014 This is an April Fool's      Joe Sewell
                  joke. Not!
```

Now I want to widen the `DESCRIPTION` column and rewrap that column **only** to the new width. Let's say, for the sake of this question, I would add the spaces myself so it would look more like this:

```
TR #  DATE        DESCRIPTION                        PROGRAMMER
----- ----------- ---------------------------------  -----------
12345 01-APR-2014 This is an April Fool's            Joe Sewell
                  joke. Not!
```

Now comes the bit I need help on. I want to perform a visual block selection (CTRL-V or CTRL-Q in gvim) on the `DESCRIPTION` column and perform an ex command or mapping to rewrap the text to the selected width, producing:

```
TR #  DATE        DESCRIPTION                        PROGRAMMER
----- ----------- ---------------------------------  -----------
12345 01-APR-2014 This is an April Fool's joke.      Joe Sewell
                  Not!
```

I can deal with the subsequent lines having trailing spaces, if necessary. I want **none** of the rest of the text on the selected lines affected. (Those familiar with EVE under OpenVMS, this is equivalent to block selecting a chunk of text and, with the EDT keypad, typing GOLD-8.) I **don't** want indentation changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My [FormatToWidth plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4924) provides a `<Leader>gq` command with which you can achieve this:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered moving the DESCRIPTION column to another buffer, setting your desired textwidth for that buffer (:set `textwidth=yournumber`), formatting with `gq`, then moving back to the original location?

Comment: I thought about that, though I'd have to derive textwidth based on the width of the selection (since it's not always consistent). I was hoping for something a little easier, but I might be able to automate that.

Comment: I was also hoping for a way to do this without having a new buffer appear & disappear from the screen.